# Ruby on Rails Controller WHERE statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am searching the database for a unique key and I am getting it back but as an array I then have to take the first object and send that to my view

```
def watch
  @video = Video.where("key = ?", params[:key])
  @video = @video[0]
end
```

I feel like I am doing this the wrong way. Key is always unique so it will never return more than one object, I always want the first object. How can I make this one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Rails <= 3.2.x you should use: `@video = Video.find_by_key!(params[:key])`

On Rails > 3.2.x you should use: `@video = Video.find_by!(key: params[:key])`

Those forms are preferred, because they raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound and the controller return the 404 HTTP code to the client.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by-21

Answer (score 8):

```
@video = Video.where("key =?" , params[:key]).first
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
@video = Video.find_by_key(params[:key])
```

Or

```
@video = Video.where(key: params[:key]).first
```

These return `nil` if the key doesn't exist. If you prefer a `ResourceNotFound` exception use the *bang* methods:

```
@video = Video.find_by_key!(params[:key])
```

Or

```
@video = Video.where(key: params[:key]).first!
```

Comment: Key in my case refers to a column in the database, does this still work for that?

Comment: Oh ok I see what you're doing after reading this, Looks like .first is more appreciated as this version is more deprecated http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: These are called [dynamic finders](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders), they have been deprecated in Rails 4.